# C# How to declare a property with dot?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I know this is not recommended as per the naming convention.

There is a C# console program(.NET Framework) which was written long back in our team which fetches data from a third party storage and stores it in SQL. One of the new column in storage have name as 'ABC.XYZ'(with '.'). And we are trying to pull data for this column now.

Following the code we usually declare a property with the same name as it is there in the storage column.  Which then using **PropertyInfo** we match with the columns names fetched from the storage and pulls the data for that specific property name. But in C# class, we cannot declare a property with '.' in name -

```
public float ABC.XYZ {get; set;}
```

I tried with **[DisplayName(" ")]** attribute but that does not override the **PropertyInfo.Name** value -

```
[DisplayName("ABC.XYZ")]
public float ABC.XYZ {get; set;}
```

How can I implement this in a better way?

Comment: Since you have control over the program using this you can write the code to have it look at whatever attribute(s) of the properties you want to get the name.  You can even make your own attribute specifically for whatever information you want to convey to this process of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* have a C# property name with a `.` in it, so; that isn't an option. And adding a `[DisplayName]` doesn't change the property name - this addition is *only* visible to code that explicitly checks for property data. It sounds like you have your own code that checks to do the lookups, though. You can educate *that* code to *check* for a `[DisplayName]` (or similar), for example:

```cs
PropertyInfo prop = // ... your code here;

var dn = (DisplayNameAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
var name = dn?.DisplayName; // use the display name if there is one
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    name = prop.Name; // but use the regular property name if there isn't
}
```

Note that reflection metadata lookup isn't hugely efficient; you usually want to do this as little as possible, caching the results.

Side note: personally, I'd recommend defining your own attribute for this rather than abusing `DisplayNameAttribute`. This isn't complex:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class WhateverAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName { get; }
    public WhateverAttribute(string columnName)
        => ColumnName = columnName;
}
```

and use `[Whatever("ABC.DEF")]` and remember to change `DisplayNameAttribute` to `WhateverAttribute` in the code above.

Finally, don't forget to update any SQL generation to check for `.` and use appropriate escaping - for example, in SQL Server, this column needs to be cited as `[ABC.DEF]` to avoid confusing over what you mean by `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the annotation `[Column("ABC.XYZ")]`.

Reference [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

```
[DisplayName("ABC.XYZ")]
[Column("ABC.XYZ")]
public float ABC_XYZ {get; set;}
```

Comment: This is dependent upon the code that is dealing with data access knowing to *manually check* for that attribute; it *sounds* like OP is using something ... "bespoke and unique", in which case it probably doesn't (yet).